# Why do curves stop working entirely when I try to change the Spline Type?

Tags: bezier-curves

Here is a video example of the issue
LINK:
https://streamable.com/q7089z

The same issues occurs when I change the spline type on every vertex.

Comment: Each curve type has its particularities... if not maybe only one curve type would be useful... What do you want to do?

Comment: it looks like you need  more than 4 vertices to see a curve with nurbs so if you convert a 4 vertex bezier curve or less you won't see anything

Comment: @lemon  I actually am just trying to use one curve type, Nurbs.  The thing is I want to use the curve Draw tool but it only outputs Poly or Bezier, so I'm trying to convert the Bezier to Nurb.

Comment: @moonboots  Thanks, but even then it doesn't work right.  The curve treats some verts like a vector bezier handle (red circle) and the ends of the path have no effect on the actual curve.
IMAGE LINK:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/498377815872241676/783420625188028436/unknown.png

Comment: I don't know anything about nurbs, I hope someone will help, do you have any particular reason why you use nubs instead of bezier?

Comment: @NoahGonzales Hello and welcome. While videos and links are helpful additions, questions should stand on their own. [Please provide some context and explanation, don't just post a link to a video](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)